# Is it possible to pass on additional options to docker start like (port forwarding, capabilities)

Tags: docker, containers

A container is started with limited options and then have been stopped. Is it possible to pass on additional options (like port forwarding, or mounting volumes etc) when starting a stopped container?

`docker start --help` doesn't show much of the options though!

Is committing the container to a new image and then running a new container with required options, using the newly created image, the only available option?

Answer (score 0):

If you find the need to commit a container to have your last state when restarting it, you're getting outside of the focus of containers. They should be immutable with the goal to delete and recreate them at any point, possibly running on different machines, or replicated many times.

For persistent data, you should be using volumes. With your data inside a volume, you can destroy and restart the container with the correct options like port forwarding, and still have your data without needing to commit a new image.

Comment: The container is half way in the process of creating an image, with data synched in. This data is specific to the image to be built and not required to be on a shared volume. It cannot be committed to an image half way with (loads of unnecessary data contained in it, which will be removed once the setup is done), just for the reason to add a port forwarding rule or a capability.